# Angular2 hosted on HANA Cloud Platform

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, hana

I am developing angular2 application in my local machine and I would like to host the application in HANA Cloud platform, but in cloud platform redirection is not working and getting "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found" error.

Answer (score 0):

yes.. because an angular app is contained in one single page.. the server should pass the routing `params` to this page instead of searching for a page with a specific name:
ex: `site.com/blog`
if the server looked for blog it will return a `404`.. it should pass it to the index page instead.

take a look here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5113

Comment: any idea about how to add .htacess file in Hana cloud platform, I have created one but it is not working

Comment: unfortunately no.
.htacess files are supposed to overwrite the server configuration.. but it is server specific.